# Very simple list comprehension for inventory function

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am making a game which has a player inventory system, and the inventory is a list with a limited size of 5. I limit the size of the inventory by keeping the list always 5 indices long, and fill the empty spaces with None Types.

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to find the length of the list EXCLUDING all none types in it. Im guessing this can be done more simpler with list comps that I have done below:

```
Inventory = [1, 2, None, None, 5, None]
items = [i for i in range(len(Inventory)) if Inventory[i] is not None
itemCount = len(items)
```

Comment: if you have no falsey values `len(filter(None,Inventory))`

Comment: Your list is 6 indices long in your example. You can also use empty lists and `append` or `remove` items, checking that their size does not exceed 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> Inventory = [1, 2, None, None, 5, None]
```

Using a list comp

```
>>> len([i for i in Inventory if i is not None])
3
```

Using `filter`

```
>>> len(filter(lambda i : i is not None, Inventory))
3
```

The way `filter` works, is that it takes a function, and a list, and removes things based on the function. So I could make a function like so

```
def checkIfNotNone(item):
    return item is not None
```

Then I could use `filter` to make the following list.

```
filter(checkIfNotNone, Inventory)
[1, 2, 5]
```

So now I can check `len` and it will be `3`. I did the same thing, but instead of writing a function using `def` I used a `lambda` expression, which is basically an anonymous function that I only intended to use in that context.

Comment: `len(filter(lambda x: x is not None,Inventory))`

Comment: @Jacob I added some explanation of the `filter` method. Let me know if there is anything specific that you are still confused about.

Answer (score 2):

This takes the length of the list of items in Inventory that aren't None:

```
len([item for item in Inventory if item is not None])
```

This simply counts how often None occurs, and subtracts it from the fixed length:

```
5 - Inventory.count(None)
```

Comment: I quite like the `count()` way, just generalise with `len(Inventory)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> Inventory = [1, 2, None, None, 5, None]
>>> len(filter(None, Inventory))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the `None`s and subtract it from the total length:

```
>>> Inventory = [1, 2, None, None, 5, None]
>>> len(Inventory)-Inventory.count(None)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Several answers so far often use `len(filter(...))` which won't work in Python 3, because `filter` now returns a generator, rather than a list. An alternative that works in all versions of Python is:

```
sum(x is not None for x in Inventory)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `True` is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`.

But if you have exactly one kind of invalid value (e.g. `None`), the solution suggested by RemcoGerlich is probably the fastest possible:

```
len(Inventory) - Inventory.count(None)
```

This should be fast because `list.count` is implemented in C, so there's no Python code running in a loop (as there will be with any list comprehension or generator expression).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: inventory = [1, 2, None, None, 5, None]

In [2]: sum(map(bool, inventory))
Out[2]: 3
```